# getOccupiedLocations Gridworld

Tags: gridworld

So basically what I have to do is add crabcritters to gridworld randomly, which I did. Then, I need to use the getOccupiedLocations method to print an array of the occupied locations as ordered pairs. Any advice? Here's what I have so far:

```
package projects.critters;
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld; 
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
public class Lab
{    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
        {
            world.add (new CrabCritter());
        }
        world.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag

Answer (score 0):

OK so the method getOccupiedLocations() returns an array of Locations.  I don't know exactly what you mean by ordered pairs but if you mean (x, y) then that is easy to do.  By default when you print out a Location it is an ordered pair.  So all you have to do is loop through the occupied locations and print each out.  For example:

```
for(Location l : world.getGrid().getOccupiedLocations()){
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

And that's it...as for the comment: you don't need a language tag as this is a GridWorld question which obviously applies to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on John Smith's answer. If you only want to print locations occupied by CrabCritter only, you can do this:

```
for(Location l : world.getGrid().getOccupiedLocations()){
    if(world.get(l) instanceof CrabCritter)
        System.out.println(l);
}
```